# Is there any way to make a dynamic formatting with query?

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have a complex sheet made by a query, and I would like to combine colors and borders to make easier to use. But as the size of the tables changes dynamically, I guess I have to add something like format commands into the query formula. But I don´t know if that is possible. For example, changing the colors of column A depending on the Values of column B. Or defining the external borders of a table although the size of the table is not always the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no, this is not possible to manage from `QUERY`

for color change, you will need to use **Conditional formatting** (with **custom formula** if it's more complex)

and I guess you should give up on `border color change` as well as `marge cell dynamicity` (this can be controlled only by a script and even then it's tricky)